# D3 Y Axis in gap of 25 numbers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, d3.js

I have below D3 js code -

```
const svg = select(svgRef.current);
const { width, height } = wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
const stackGenerator = stack().keys(keys);
const layers = stackGenerator(data);

const extent = [0, 100];

const yScale = scaleLinear().domain(extent).range([height, 0]);

const x0Scale = scaleBand()
  .domain(data.map((d) => d.name))
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.46);
const x1Scale = scaleBand()
  // .domain(data.map((d) => d.type))
  .rangeRound([0, x0Scale.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.12);

const xAix = axisBottom(x0Scale);
const yAix = axisLeft(yScale);
svg.select(".x-axis").attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`).call(xAix);

svg
  .select(".y-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${0 + 25}, 0 )`)
  .call(yAix);
```

I have extent 0 to 100 for Y Axis. I am getting Y-Axis in the group of 10 points - `(0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)`

I want to plot it in the gap of 25 - `(0,25,50,75,100)`

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating the `y-axis` you can pass the number of `ticks` that you want to render

```
svg
  .select(".y-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${0 + 25}, 0 )`)
  .call(yAix.ticks(5));
```

the other way would be using `tickValues`

```
svg
  .select(".y-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${0 + 25}, 0 )`)
  .call(yAix.tickValues([0,25,50,75,100]));
```